# Is it safe to use rds.DatabaseInstanceFromSnapshot long term?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cdk

Is it safe to keep a database in CDK as
`this.database = new rds.DatabaseInstanceFromSnapshot(this, 'name', {...})`

I'm concerned that the database might get accidentally deleted at some point in the future. There was an incident recently where we had checked out the wrong commit and ran cdk deploy without checking the diff. Had we not stopped it, it would have deleted the database. It feels safer to me to move the database config to:

`this.database = rds.DatabaseInstanceBase.fromDatabaseInstanceAttributes(this, 'backendAPIDatabase', {`

However, the downside of this approach is that if I run cdk deploy, it wants to delete the DB Subnet Groups and Parameter Groups that were originally created.

Comment: What do you mean by "accidentally deleted"?

Comment: There was an incident recently where we had checked out the wrong commit and ran cdk deploy without checking the diff. Had we not stopped it, it would have deleted the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default when using `rds.DatabaseInstanceFromSnapshot` the [`DeletionPolicy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-deletionpolicy.html) is set to `Retain`:

> AWS CloudFormation keeps the resource without deleting the resource or its contents when its stack is deleted.

Moreover, the [`UpdateReplacePolicy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-updatereplacepolicy.html) is also set to `Retain`:

> Use the UpdateReplacePolicy attribute to retain or (in some cases) backup the existing physical instance of a resource when it is replaced during a stack update operation.

Finally, [deletion protection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_DeleteInstance.html#USER_DeleteInstance.DeletionProtection) is enabled by default as well. This prevents accidental deletions via the console, CLI or API:

> You can only delete instances that don't have deletion protection enabled.

See [`applyRemovalPolicy`](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/v1.22.0/packages/@aws-cdk/aws-rds/lib/instance.ts#L912-L914) and [`deletionProtection`](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/v1.22.0/packages/@aws-cdk/aws-rds/lib/instance.ts#L532) in the code.